# 'Collection was of a fixed size.' exception: Is it an error or a bug in System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I have studied several SO answers citing this exception (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3957136/5438626)) without success. Also, my example to reproduce the behavior is the most minimal that I've seen. As a control for reproducing this issue, I have this constant string:

```
const string json =
@"{
    ""ArrayOfString"": [""Hello World""]
  }";
```

And `ClassA`:

```
class ClassA
{
    public string[] ArrayOfString { get; set; }
}
```

There are **no issues** deserializing `ClassA` whether I do it with `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`.

```
ClassA classA;
classA = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(json);
classA = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClassA>(json);
```

Now consider `ClassB` where the same property has a backing store in `BaseClass`.

```
class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public string[] ArrayOfString
    {
        get => new string[] { base.SingularString };
        set
        {
            if((value != null) && (value.Length == 1))
            {
                base.SingularString = value[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
class BaseClass
{
    public string SingularString { get; set; } = "Hello World";
}
```

It doesn't seem like a big ask to have `ClassB` deserialize from the same `json` source.

```
ClassB classB;
classB = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassB>(json);
classB = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClassB>(json);
```

`Newtonsoft` doesn't have any beef doing this:

[image: newtonsoft watch]

However, `System.Text.Json` throws when asked to do the same thing:

[image: system.text.json]

Does anyone have first-hand knowledge of [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29843) which was closed more than 2 years ago? Is this a reemergence of that? Or am simply making an error of some kind? And yeah, I get it. The collection *is* a fixed size but why would that matter?

Comment: I can't reproduce on .NET 6, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhRYJP.  What version are you using? ... According to [this pull](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/39442) the issue was fixed in .NET 5.

Comment: @dbc per tag it's .NET core 3.1. I'll go ahead and try it on 5/6 and see what's up. Thx.

Comment: Confirmed. Works correctly with .NET 5 or .NET 6. Fails with .NET Core 3.1 (tried it in VS 2019 and VS 2022 with the same result). **You have answered my question** thank you that's the certainty I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bug that was fixed in .NET 5.**  See pull [Replace collection instances on deserialize #39442](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/39442).  A working .NET 6 fiddle can be seen here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhRYJP.

If you must develop against .NET Core 3.1, your options would appear to include:

1. Introduce a custom converter for `ClassB`.
2. Use a `List<string>` instead of a `string []` for `ArrayOfString`:

   ```
   class ClassB : BaseClass
   {
       public List<string> ArrayOfString
       {
           get => new List<string>() { base.SingularString };
           set
           {
               if((value != null) && (value.Count == 1))
               {
                   base.SingularString = value[0];
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (Note that if you are still targeting both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft, `List<string>` will not work with the latter.  See e.g. *[Why are all the collections in my POCO are null when deserializing some valid json with the .NET Newtonsoft.Json component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32491966/3744182)* for why.)